# AutoPostBack with select on click

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

i have 3 `select` inputs in a `form`, that represents the date. one is day, one is month and one is the year.

the options to those selects are added by using javascript: so for example if the year that is chosen is divideable by 4 and the month is February then there will be 29 days in the day `selecet` otherwise there will be only 28. -this works, i didnt know if it relates to the problem so i brought it anyway.

now if you want to enter a date you have start with the year and month first, so the code will know how many days to add to the day `select`.

so i have used `asp.net` on this and every time the day `selecet` is being selected before  the month and the year has been entered there is a `<td id="dateE">` that becomes visible and in it written to enter a month and a year first.

**the problem is** that it doesnt work- when you click on the day `select` before the year and the month `select`s nothing happens-there is no error and the website doesnt fail or anything.

this select has `runat=server` and `autopostback=true` and i have tried with `onclick` with `onserverclick` with `onfocus` nothing worked.

here the code:

html:

```
    <body  onload ="addDate()">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr><td>
        Birth Date:
        <br />
        <select id="Day" name="Day" class="regis" style="width:109px" onfocus="Day_Click" runat="server" autopostback="true">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Day</option>
        </select>
        /
        <select id="Month" name="Month" class="regis" onchange="updateDay()" style="width:109px">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Month</option>
        </select>
        /
        <select id="Year" name="Year" class="regis" onchange="yearChanged()" style="width:109px">
        <option value="" selected="selected" >Year</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td class="un" id="dateE" runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
 </body>
```

css:

```
    .un
    {
        display:none;  
    }
    .feedback
    {
        border-top:1px solid black;
        border-left:1px solid black;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
.regis
{
   border: 1px solid rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.9);
   background-color: #fff;
   background: transparent;
   height:25px;
}
```

javascript:

```
    function addYear() {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    var legalWorkingAge = currentYear - 16;
    var select = document.getElementById("Year");
    for (var i = legalWorkingAge; i >= 1900; i--) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
    } //for
} //addYear
function addMonth() {
    var select = document.getElementById("Month");
    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
    } //for
} //addMonth
function addDay(month) {
    var select = document.getElementById("Day");
    while (select.options.length != 1) {
        select.options.remove(1);
    }
    var daynum;
    switch (parseInt(month)) {
        case 1: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 2:
            var year = document.getElementById("Year");
            var selectedYear = year.options[year.selectedIndex].value;
            if (parseInt(selectedYear) % 4 == 0)
                daynum = 29;
            else
                daynum = 28;
            break;
        case 3: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 4: daynum = 30;
            break;
        case 5: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 6: daynum = 30;
            break;
        case 7: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 8: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 9: daynum = 30;
            break;
        case 10: daynum = 31;
            break;
        case 11: daynum = 30;
            break;
        case 12: daynum = 31;
            break;
    } //switch
    for (var i = 1; i <= daynum; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
    } //for
} //addDay

function addDate() {
    addMonth();
    addYear();
} //addDate
function updateDay() {
    var month = document.getElementById("Month");
    var selectedMonth = month.options[month.selectedIndex].value;
    addDay(selectedMonth);
}
function yearChanged() {
    var month = document.getElementById("Month");
    var selectedMonth = month.options[month.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedMonth != "")
        updateDay()
}
```

asp.net:

```
public void Day_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dateE.InnerText = "Enter a Month and a Year First";
    this.dateE.Attributes.Add("class", "feedback");
}
```

Its driving me carzy, i have looked where is the problem so many times and i just cant find it.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using control from `HtmlControls` namespace - that complicates everything a bit.

First of all, most events that you might use, like `onclick`, `onfocus` etc. for these controls are client-side as for regular HTML tags. Therefore they are not even triggering postback to the server, not to mention validation and server-side event handlers.

Different `HtmlControl` inheritors have different server-side events defined to make at least some interaction with server possible. Some of them do not have anything at all, but the `select` you are using has [OnServerChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.onserverchange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defined. This is the only one you can use to track on server that something has happened to the control.

Of course you can still use client-side like `onfocus` or `onclick`, but that would mean writing client-side handler that triggers the postback manually. Possible, but a bit tricky.

Another good option to consider is to use `asp:DropDownList` control, which is rendered as `select`, but should be more convenient to use on the server.

Finally, the very thing you are trying to do seems to fit better to the entirely client-side solution. That is you should be able to control visibility/access to the selects via javascript pretty easily. Have you considered that approach?

Comment: Thanks ill just do the client side solution